# Facebook does not get metatags on 301 redirect

Tags: facebook, apache, http

I have little hope that I will be able to fix this issue, but I figured I would ask.

We have a domain that is being forwarded (using apache) to another page. We want people to have the appropriate meta tags when they type in "x.org" to share it on Facebook, but instead facebook shows "301 Moved Permanently".  Is there any way to have Facebook use the meta tags from the page it is redirected to, or am I SOL?

This is what the facebook debugger sees.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.x.org/page/s/15">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.x.org Port 80</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the URL? And you are sure that you are sending a 301 header?

Comment: url is http://www.15atwalmart.org